# Does "case .. of" supports a fallthrough in Elm?

Tags: pattern-matching, elm

Javascript's `switch` supports a fallthrough:

```
function update(action, model) {
  switch (action) {
    case SHUFFLE:
      return shuffle(model);

    case MOVE_LEFT:
    case MOVE_RIGHT:
    case MOVE_UP:
    case MOVE_DOWN:
      return move(action, model);

    default:
      return model;
  }
}
```

How would you implement this in Elm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would model it like this:

```
type Direction = Left | Right | Up | Down


type Action = Shuffle | Move Direction 


update action model =
  case action of 
    Shuffle -> shuffle model 
    Move dir -> move dir model
```

Elm's case does not have fall-through.

> "a case-expression does not have fall through, so you don't need to say break everywhere to make things sane."

http://elm-lang.org/guide/model-the-problem

Comment: It seems the link no longer contains that info!

Comment: The documentation shifted around and now we have a larger Guide for Elm. The old address redirects to the Union Types page that contains all the relevant information.

Answer (score 4):

I think **pdamoc**'s answer is the best for what you're trying to do. However, in the interest of completeness, no Elm cases do not support fallthrough. The best solution is to extract the common code into a function. If you model your data well, you can reduce the number of different cases that call this function.

Case expressions support default using `_ -> code`, which should always be the last case, since it will match anything. You should avoid using this if you can; in 0.16 the compiler will detect unhandled cases for you.

Finally, you can use `if` and equality on union tags, but it's generally worse than using `case`.

```
if List.member action [MoveLeft, MoveRight, MoveUp, MoveDown]
then move action model
else shuffle model
```